# Redirect user in passport deserialize function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passport js in my node/express application and i plan to do a response redirect in passport deserialize based on certain conditions. I try above method but failed.

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });

        if(conditions) {
            res.redirect('/'); // cannot read property redirect of undefined
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how do you use that function in your application?

Comment: @OlegMeleshko could you explain more on what do you mean? thax

Comment: where do you use this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use `res` in `deserializeUser` because it is not available there. You only have the `done` callback that you use to tell Passport if deserialization succeeded and a user was found. Maybe you could call `done(null, null)`?